# postgresql pqxx notify_listener - getting notify payload

Tags: postgresql, libpqxx

Native interface postgresql provides the following command:`NOTIFY channel [ , payload ]`, where payload is variable string. I use library `pqxx` for interaction with database. It provides  `notify_listener` interface. The callback which executed as notification have just one parameter - `id`. 
This is my code:

```
class notif : public pqxx::notify_listener {

public:
        notif(pqxx::connection_base &conn, const std::string &table, std::shared_ptr<notify_processor_t> pr) : 
            pqxx::notify_listener(conn, table), _table(table), _pr(pr) {}

        notif(pqxx::connection_base &conn, const std::string &table) :
            pqxx::notify_listener(conn, table), _table(table) {}

        virtual void operator()(int id) 
        { 
            std::cout << "notification " << _table << std::endl; 
            if (_pr.get())
                _pr->operator()();
        }
private:
        std::shared_ptr<notify_processor_t> _pr;
        std::string _table;
};
```

How I can get the `payload` content using `pqxx` interface provided?

Answer (score 2):

Found the following in libpqxx 4.0.1 version:

```
// Obsolete notification receiver.
/** @deprecated Use notification_receiver instead.
*/
class PQXX_LIBEXPORT PQXX_NOVTABLE notify_listener
```

You should use  `notification receiver` class instead of `notify_listener`